# Syncing SQLite table over devices

Tags: android, sqlite, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible that I store my SQLite table over a dropbox account and have all my users sync their tables with the stored table? Also be able to make changes to that table?

Comment: NO. Data over the web doesn't work like that. You need a server and some webServices. As you plan to do, your users would have to download a copy of the shared db and you're not granted that all of them hve the same copy. And you can be sure that they won't see the modifications done by the oter users.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to make that work then? Any tutorials? I have zero experience with working with servers and webservices.

Comment: Man, it's really a `broad argument`... I'll try to synthesize to the bones. **1** - You need a computer (server) where a DB engine runs (no matter which RDBMS you choose). **2** - On the same machine, a program (again, no matter in which language you develop it) shares data by parsing requests and giving back results (in form of an encoded string). **3** - On the consumer side, you get the data and do whatever you want. Even store them locally, if you really need to. That's the most synthetic explanation I could give.

Comment: Thanks for that although I was blank at most of it but I'll look into it.

Comment: Use Google and you'll find a zillion of tutorials on the argument.

Comment: Yeap already on it. Thanks!

Comment: Your're welcome. It is however something that requires some planning and some study. Don't think of it as a weekend project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach could work in theory, but there are so many issues involved, that you're better off not doing it. If you wish to store and make data available across all devices belonging to a user, I strongly recommend looking into [Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) by Dropbox. The API will take care of storing data locally as well as synchronize it over connected Dropbox accounts.

If you want a bit modular approach, you can use Windows Azure Mobile Services. These give you REST APIs to store your data in cloud. However, synchronization has to be handled by the developer - you. I have written a small library to do that here: http://bit.ly/ProjectMirror It's for Windows Phone, but Android version is already in a sister repo there. You could extend it. Let us know how that goes.

In addition to these services, [Parse SDK](https://www.parse.com/) is a good option. It requires you to pay after a while, though. In addition to what you want to do, it also provides other things like user management and so on. But, be aware that some of those operations may require you a live Internet connection.

So, in essence, if you want seamless data storage and sync, use Datastore. Be aware that you'll have no control over the server side. Also, your data will be restricted to the Dropbox ecosystem forever. If you plan on further expanding your app to other platforms, go with Azure and handle the sync. If you want lots of features, go with the Parse.

Comment: I was looking into the datastore API after posting this question. Will look into it further thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into Google Play Game Services using the [Cloud Save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave) feature. Even if you are not building a game this feature lets you sync sqlite data in the cloud and Google will handle most of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

OR you could use a cloud based database which supports both push and pull. That means:

Scenario 1: 
Your users change something on their phones. Changes are uploaded to the database. The database then pushes these changes to all other users.

Scenario 2: 
Your users change something and upload this to the database. But instead of the cloud based server pushing the changes to all users, the users phones can ask the database for new data at intervals.

All this is very easy to set up. It took me about five, ten minutes. Just follow this easy tutorial:

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

and for push:

https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

We now use this for our company app, storing statistics for example.

Bear in mind that syncing can become complex. Try to keep it very simple, especially if you are new at programming.